# Unable to login with fresh moqui setup

Tags: moqui

I have cloned moqui framework from [repo](https://github.com/moqui/moqui-framework.git), followed #6 [Build and Run From Source](https://www.moqui.org/docs/framework/Run+and+Deploy)

- Cloned moqui-framework
- get the PopCommerce component using following task
  ./gradlew getComponent -Pcomponent=PopCommerce
- Run the command ./gradlew build
- Run the command ./gradlew load
- Run the command ./gradlew run

While accessing http://localhost:8080/Login, I am unable to login with username "john.doe" and password "moqui".

Here are the logs for reference

> Created 1284 automatic reverse relationships 13:12:54.698  INFO
>   RequireNewTx                 o.m.i.e.EntityDataFeed Built
>   entity.data.feed.info cache for in 250ms, entries for 56 entities
>   13:12:54.713  INFO 626202354-98                 o.m.i.c.UserFacadeImpl
>   Created new Visit with ID [100303] in session
>   [node01o3pl6oc1kf4jel2dej0wb8qi0] 13:12:54.991  INFO 626202354-98
>   o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl Redirecting to /Login instead of rendering
>   [vapps] 13:12:55.078  INFO 626202354-98
>   o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl vapps [] in 352ms (text/html;charset=utf-8)
>   session node01o3pl6oc1kf4jel2dej0wb8qi0 13:12:55.096  INFO
>   626202354-98                 o.m.i.c.UserFacadeImpl Created new Visit
>   with ID [100304] in session [node0ngjq8w6q3af0oeeusu9atiqt1]
>   13:12:55.422  INFO 626202354-98               o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl
>   Login [] in 326ms (text/html;charset=utf-8) session
>   node0ngjq8w6q3af0oeeusu9atiqt1 13:12:58.087  INFO 626202354-88
>   o.m.i.c.UserFacadeImpl Created new Visit with ID [100305] in session
>   [node01c81rspmysows167mr8kc2tyor2] 13:12:58.135  INFO 626202354-88
>   o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl Transition Login/login in 47ms, redirecting
>   to screen path URL: http://localhost:8080/vapps 13:12:58.148  INFO
>   626202354-90                 o.m.i.c.UserFacadeImpl Created new Visit
>   with ID [100306] in session [node01p58shv6twbq90ok4bp8qkg03]
>   13:12:58.149  INFO 626202354-90               o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl
>   Redirecting to /Login instead of rendering [vapps] 13:12:58.150  INFO
>   626202354-90               o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl vapps [] in 1ms
>   (text/html;charset=utf-8) session node01p58shv6twbq90ok4bp8qkg03
>   13:12:58.155  INFO 626202354-99                 o.m.i.c.UserFacadeImpl
>   Created new Visit with ID [100307] in session
>   [node018szf3vj1hlzy1rurp99n2ypol4] 13:12:58.174  INFO 626202354-99
>   o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl Login [] in 19ms (text/html;charset=utf-8)
>   session node018szf3vj1hlzy1rurp99n2ypol4 13:12:58.263  INFO
>   oquiWorker-1          o.moqui.i.c.MessageFacadeImpl IP address is not
>   a public address

Comment: This isn't really a question that might have a direct answer. The project mailing lists might be a better place to ask for help. From the log it looks like it might have something to do with the session cookie in browser/client, ie either cookies are disabled or there is a stale cookie conflict or something.

Comment: Thanks David for your quick response, Yes it seems cookie related issue, If I run the application on incognito mode its working fine.